# ancestry gem with position sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drag-and-drop, ancestry

I use ancestry gem for create nested categories. this gem is super fast but how can i add position filed to ancestry.
I want tree item sort by parent and child & position. think you create category like:

games
 - football
 - tennis

after a while you add another child to games like boxing

games
 - football
 - tennis
 - boxing

but you want show boxing above the tennis like :

games
 - football
 - boxing
 - tennis

and this was nice to be down by a drag and drop. how should i do add position to view and is it possible a simple way to drag and drop. i tried to use the gem that recommended by ancestry but it have lot of unfixed bug.

Comment: that's Okey but does it make any sense to you because you can get the records based on updated at.

Comment: i don't want to sort by update time , sort by an ordering integer column

Comment: @Armanlearn is your issue resolved?

Comment: @SachinSingh , Yes, I solved this, do you have same problems?

Comment: @Armanlearn I have the same issue, how did you solve it?

Comment: You can use this gem in conjunction with `acts_as_list` to implement ordering